# I want to remove windows 8 and keep ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-8, bios

I have been testing out ubuntu for a few months now and now I decided to keep it on my system (It's a dual boot with windows 8.1).
**My question is : If I remove windows 8.1 from my system, will my BIOS also be removed?**

I was going to uninstall Windows 8.1 with OS-Uninstaller.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller

My BIOS is an American Megatrends BIOS.
Ubuntu Version : 15.04
Laptop brand : Asus (Notebook PC)
Dual Boot with : Windows 8.1
I also have the GRUB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the definition of BIOS from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS .

The answer is : no your BIOS will not be removed.

Comment: Thank you! I tought the bios was part of the windows OS (My laptop came with windows 8)